# Auto detect file encoding when downloading tfs files

Tags: c#, tfs, file-encodings

I am downloading TFS files by creating workspace as follows

```
   Workspace newWorkspace = verControlServer.CreateWorkspace(workspaceName, 
   verControlServer.AuthorizedUser); 
   //some extra code here
```

After this i am mapping files to local folder. As follows.
          //some more code lines here
       Localpath = workspaceName.GetLocalItemForServerItem(ServerItem);

If any of the TFS files contains other language characters such as chinese then i get "????" in the file which i am unable to run using powershell. 
Is there a way to find the file encoding for the files downloaded using TFS APIs.

Comment: any idea please??

Comment: Special characters in file content or file name?

Comment: Special characters in file content.  How can we find the file format in TFS?